# How much more revenue does that greater revenue model predicts over the 3 year period from 2035 through 2037?

Tags: calculus

Given two revenue models (in millions of dollars) for a large corporation, where both models are estimates of revenues from 2015 through 2040 and $t=0$ corresponds to the beginning of 2015.
I) Which model predicts the greater revenue?

A) $R=6.68+0.16t+0.01t^2$

B) $R=6.68+0.25t+0.07t^2$

Note that 2015 refers to $t=0$ and 2040 refers to $t=25$. Then I solved
$$\int_0^25 B-A dt$$
which was positive which implies that model B predicts the greater revenue.

II) How much more revenue does that greater revenue model predicts over the 3 year period from 2035 through 2037?

I tried the following approaches but I don't get the answer 89.145.

Attempt 1: $\int_{20}^{22} B dt$

Attempt 2: $\int_{20}^{22} B-A dt$

Attempt 3: Plug in $t=20,21,22$ into model B and sum them.

I feel the wording of the problem is what is confusing me. Can I get any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the problem statement, we have

$$\int_{20}^{23} \left(\left(0.07 t^2+0.25 t+6.68\right)-\left(0.01 t^2+0.16 t+6.68\right)\right) \, dt = 89.145$$

Comment: Why 23 and not 22?

Comment: Because they are asking over three years. We start at $2015$ and at $2035$ that is $20$ years and then the problem says for three years, so that is $23$.